# Correct headers and mime_type for PHP http streaming

Tags: php, html, audio, http-headers

I've been fighting with this for a few days now. I can't seem to get anything to play through PHP. I'm trying to play a `.m4a` audio file through php and all it does is show the HTML5 player in Chrome but the file does not load.

**I've tried numerous tricks from other posts here and nothing seems to make a difference.**

Here is some back end info.

Apache/Linux Server with PHP-FPM running [H264 Streaming module](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2). 
`AddType audio/mp4 m4a` is added in the vhost file.

All files are `.m4a` that was encoded with ffmpeg and used the `-c:a aac -strict experimental` in ffmpeg as the audio codec. The file itself plays just fine directly in the browser, just not through PHP. Funny thing is when I changed the mime to audio/acc it played in the browser but through quicktime player. I need it to be native HTML5 m4a.

Here is the PHP code I'm trying to use. I've tried many combos including using Content-Disposition but that tries to download and save it then. i don't want that.

```
        $size = filesize($realfile);
        $mimes = "audio/mp4";
        if(file_exists($realfile)){
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
            header('Content-Range: bytes 0-'.($size - 1).'/'.$size);
            header('Content-Type: '.$mimes);
            readfile($realfile);
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
        }
```

Here are the response headers using the PHP URL. (Does NOT play)

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:3340918
Content-Range:bytes 0-3340917/3340918
Content-Type:audio/mp4
Date:Fri, 17 Apr 2015 21:47:21 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.22
```

Here is the response headers from the URL of the file directly. (Plays fine)

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:3340918
Content-Range:bytes 0-3340917/3340918
Content-Type:audio/mp4
Date:Fri, 17 Apr 2015 21:29:04 GMT
ETag:"32fa76-5139745cc934f"
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 13 Apr 2015 08:55:15 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9
```

Any help on this would be great.

**EDIT: I finally gave up with this code. I found a PHP script on GitHub that does exactly what I need and it works perfectly.**

https://github.com/tuxxin/MP4Streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally gave up with this code. I found a PHP script on GitHub that does exactly what I need and it works perfectly.

https://github.com/tuxxin/MP4Streaming

I needed audio so in this new script I just changed `video/mp4` to `audio/mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

The headers are effectively identical, so that isn't your problem.

I suspect the issue is that you say you accept range requests, but nowhere in your code are you actually honoring those range requests.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I added a range but it made no difference. Also I think that's a pretty thought out question with my code and examples. Not sure why I would get a downvote for this question.

Comment: @PanamaJack Well, you could ask the person that downvoted you.  And, where in your code are you loading the specific range?

Comment: How do you know who downvoted? I tried it in my code but I did not update the question with it. I added it to my PHP code in the Accept Range and it made no difference. But the other code seems to work though that I found.

Comment: @PanamaJack You don't know who downvoted... that's my point.  I don't know either, but it wasn't me.  I think had you handled the range header it would have been fine.  From what you're saying, you never did that.

Comment: Thanks but yes I did try it after you mentioned it. I did not work. I tried it in my code for Accept Range. Adding the range didn't help it. But thanks for the suggestions.